# No mapping found with URI [/SampleSpringMaven/hello.html] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcher'

Tags: spring-mvc

Im new to Spring MVC creating basic hello world example for Spring MVC but getting the message:

> HNo Mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SampleSpringMaven/hello.html] in DispatcherServlet with name dispatcher

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<a href="hello.html">Call Controller</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I Created web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**After this Dispatcher-servelet.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mvc.controller" />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/pages/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:annotation-config/>
</beans>
```

**Then I created the HelloWorldController.java**

```
package com.mvc.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    @RequestMapping("SampleSpringMaven/hello")
    public ModelAndView printMessage()
    {
        String message = "Hello World, Spring 3.0!";
        System.out.println("reached here");
        return new ModelAndView("hello", "message", message);
    }
}
```

But not able to get the response and requested resource not avialble comes on page in Tomcat logs I see the error : No Mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SampleSpringMaven/hello.html] in DispatcherServlet with name dispatcher

Comment: Corrected the request mapping to : @RequestMapping("hello")

Comment: try changing it to `/hello` if it works

Comment: and you didnt create hello.jsp anywhere.

Comment: I tried with /hello as well..same error and yes hello.jsp resides under the /WEB-INF/pages folder

Comment: `<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"><property name="viewClass"    value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
 </bean>`